# Cant get PhoneGap to access IOS camera. Button issues

Tags: javascript, html, ios, cordova, phonegap

I cannot get my button to click and access my camera and other functionality.

My HTML portion of the code. I do have all of the necessary plugins installed. And I am able to view the buttons I created. But nothing happens when they are clicked.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-2"> </div>
    <div id="imgDiv" class="col-sm-5 col-xs-11 thumbnail">
      <img src="#" alt="Image" id="img" />
      <div class="text-center">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btPhotoLib">Photo</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary active" id="btCamera">Camera</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btUpload">Upload</button>   
      </div>                        
    </div>              
</div>
```

My JS file:

```
var imgURI;
var serverURL ="ajlnfioej/upload.php";

$(document).ready(function(){
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', getCameraReady, false);    
});

function getCameraReady(){
    $('#btCamera').on('click', function(e){
        options = {quality:50, destinationType: Camera.Destination.FILE_URI,     sourceType: pictureSource.CAMERA};

        navigator.camera.getPicture(photoSuccess, photoFail,[options]);     
        }); 

    $('#btPhotoLib').on('click', function(e){
    options = {quality:50, destinationType: Camera.Destination.FILE_URI, sourceType: pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY};
    navigator.camera.getPicture(photoSuccess, photoFail,[options]);
});

$('#btUpload').on('click', function(e){
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey = "file";
    options.fileName = imgURI.substr(imgURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";

    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    var server = encodeURI(serverURL);
    ft.upload(imgURI, server,uploadSuccess, uploadFail,options);        
});
}


function photoSuccess(uri){
    $("#img").attr("src", uri);
    $("#img").css("width": "100%", "height": "100%");
    imgURI = uri;
}

function cameraError(message){
    navigator.notification.alert("camera usage not supported on this device");
}

function uploadSuccess(result){
navigator.camera.cleanup();
navigator.notification.alert("Number of bytes is : " + results.bytesSent);
navigator.notification.alert("Http Response is : " +results.response );


function uploadFail(){
    alert("Am error has occured: Code = " + error.code);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gone through your code and have got it working. It has been tested on Android and iOS however I was unable to test the upload.

- I have corrected some syntax errors in your javascript (there were a few missing curly brackets as well as some other minor things).
- When using JQuery to add multiple css tags you must give it an object, looks like you just missed the curly brackets.
- Added in photoFail function as it was used but not defined.
- Added error parameter to your error functions.
- `Camera.getPicture` options parameter expects an object but it was given an array.
- `Camera.Destination` is not defined, should be `Camera.DestinationType`.
- `pictureSource` is not defined, should be `Camera.PictureSourceType`.

I got most of this from checking the [cordova-plugin-camera documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/7.x/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/). I would recommend having a read through.

Here is the working code. You can view all the changes [here](https://www.diffchecker.com/YrUFWbWB).

```
var imgURI;
var serverURL ="ajlnfioej/upload.php";

$(document).ready(function(){
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', getCameraReady, false);    
});

function getCameraReady(){
    $('#btCamera').on('click', function(e){
        var options = {quality:50, destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI, sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA};

        navigator.camera.getPicture(photoSuccess, photoFail, options);     
    }); 

    $('#btPhotoLib').on('click', function(e){
        var options = {quality:50, destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI, sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY};
        navigator.camera.getPicture(photoSuccess, photoFail, options);
    });

    $('#btUpload').on('click', function(e){
        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey = "file";
        options.fileName = imgURI.substr(imgURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";

        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        var server = encodeURI(serverURL);
        ft.upload(imgURI, server,uploadSuccess, uploadFail,options);        
    });
}


function photoSuccess(uri){
    $("#img").attr("src", uri);
    $("#img").css({"width": "100%", "height": "100%"});
    imgURI = uri;
}

function cameraError(message){
    navigator.notification.alert("camera usage not supported on this device");
}

function uploadSuccess(result){
    navigator.camera.cleanup();
    navigator.notification.alert("Number of bytes is : " + result.bytesSent);
    navigator.notification.alert("Http Response is : " +result.response );
}

function uploadFail(error){
    alert("Am error has occured: Code = " + error.code);
}

function photoFail(error){
    alert("Am error has occured: Code = " + error.code);
}
```